# Rails -- fields_for not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

When I run the rails server and go to the school/new page on my site, the field with the label "school" where I can enter the school's name appears, but all the other fields under fields_for which are for entering the school administrator's info do not show up on my site -- when I use "inspect element" on my form it is like they are not even there.  Why aren't they appearing on my page?

```
<%= form_for(@school) do |f| %>
  <% if @school.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@school.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this school from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @school.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :school %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :admin do |f2| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f2.label "administrator name" %><br />
      <%= f2.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f2.label "administrator email" %><br />
      <%= f2.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f2.label "administrator gender" %><br />
      <%= f2.text_field :gender %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 <%= f.fields_for :admin do |f2| %>
```

try removing the f.

try with just this:

```
<%= fields_for :admin do |f2| %>
```

There is two way to use field_for:

A generic one. (like my example).

A nested one.

To use the nested field_for (f.field_for), your model object must be setup correctly

Ex:  Relation with @school and @admin

```
class School< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :admin
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin
end
```

In the end, there is multiple ways of using field_for depending on how you setup the relations on your model object.

This [guide](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) explain in details all the possible setup. You might find why it was not working for you.

My bet is your Admin and School model object are not in a relation, or you didn't put the accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin in your School object.

Comment: f represents @school elements .  fields_for is used alone and you may pass :something or "@something".  I don't know what guide you read, but i recommend the API doc of RoR on theire website.  There is often good code sample.  Have fun

Comment: In this post they use "f.fields_for" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613576/rails-nested-forms-attributes-not-saving-if-fields-added-with-jquery.  Can you explain it here?

Comment: Here too they use the dot before the fields_for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249160/nested-forms-in-rails-has-many-confusions.  Please explain.

Comment: @Kvass Sorry you are right, my comment was talking about the generic use.. but there is other way to use it .. see my edit in the response

Comment: Using plain `fields_for` isn't the same as using `f.fields_for`. You don't get the nested parameters as you probably want. To fix it, I had to instantiate a new record for the association, instead of having the association be nil. See my answer below

Answer (score 22):

### TLDR:

For my purposes, I had to make sure the form object's child association was populated with a new record. Originally, the parent object's child association returned nil. I just had to instantiate an object and the form rendered correctly.

---

In case anyone arrives here from Google, I had a the same problem as the poster, but the accepted answer didn't help me.

First, some background. When you use the plain `fields_for` instead of `f.fields_for`, the fields are rendered differently. The plain version (as suggested above) does not associate the fields rendered with the form's object.  Look at the different outputs:

### fields_for

```
form_for @parent_instance do |f|
  f.text_field :parent_field
  fields_for :child_obj do |child_fields|
    child_fields.text_field :child_field
  end
end
```

Renders

```
<input id="parent_class_parent_field" name="parent_class[parent_field]" type="text" />
<input id="child_class_child_field" name="child_class[child_field]" type="text" />
```

Which Rails will parse into these parameters:

```
{ "parent_class" => {
      "parent_field" => "Parent field value"
    },
  "child_class" => {
      "child_field" => "Child field value"
    }
}
```

### f.fields_for

```
form_for @parent_instance do |f|
  f.text_field :parent_field
  f.fields_for :child_obj do |child_fields|
    child_fields.text_field :child_field
  end
end
```

Renders

```
<input id="parent_class_parent_field" name="parent_class[parent_field]" type="text" />
<input id="parent_class_child_class_child_field" name="parent_class[child_class][child_field]" type="text" />
```

Which Rails will parse into these parameters:

```
{ "parent_class" => {
      "parent_field" => "Parent field value",
      "child_class" => {
          "child_field" => "Child field value"
        }
    }
}
```

---

The difference is that **the child object's parameters only get nested under the parent when you use `f.fields_for`.** So using the accepted answer's suggestion of using the bare `fields_for` didn't work for creating an associated record.

Turned out, the reason `f.fields_for` wasn't rendering anything was because the child association was nil. To fix it and have my form render correctly *and* return the parameters in the properly nested way, I had to instantiate that association like this in my controller:

```
def new
  @parent = ParentClass.new
  @parent.child_obj = ChildClass.new
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Sometimes though, it will not be practical to instantiate the object. In those cases, it is possible to supply the object to the fields for command like 


`f.fields_for :child, child_instance`

Comment: Perhaps you could add what to do when the child association is a `has_many` relationship.

Comment: +1 on the suggestion. Great answer, but still confused on what to do when the association is `has_many` since it will be multiple child objects instead of one.